# How can I automate a few steps in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide

For example - Anytime I make any changes in any project I have to rebuild around 2-3 projects present in the workspace.
Is there any solution that, just by typing some shortcut keys it may start debugging those particular projects automatically.

Comment: Import all the projects into your workspace and choose build automatically under project tab

Comment: alt -> p -> n -> enter

Comment: I am sorry if I could not explain the question properly, my question is- 
right click on .java -> debug as -> Java Application
I have to automate the above step for some particular projects.

Comment: I'm still not sure of the question exactly, if it is the matter of launching several projects at the same time you can do that with a custom launch configuration that will launch all 3 at once (in a specified order or in parallel). If on the other hand you need extra functionality, you could look into EASE https://www.eclipse.org/ease/